# SAS how to prepare variables before modeling

Tags: variables, sas, grouping, modeling

i have to make a credit risk model in SAS.
In data I have about 300 variables and I have to prepare them before modeling. I have to group every variables by 3 categories. I don't know how to group them. I thought to count variance and then divide them? But I don't know in what way and how to do this in SAS. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Sory, I am unsure what you are asking. 
Do you want to have 3 groups of about 100 variables that are closely correlated?
Do you want to normalize the data (like in https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/sas/faq/how-do-i-standardize-variables-in-sas/)?
Or still something else.

Comment: I have to divide every variable into 3 categories. For example age (<18),  (<35) and (>=35). There too many variables in data to make this manually. if i have to divide them into these categories, i cant normalize them later?

Comment: How much observations (data rows) do you have? Do you need to do this once, or regularry? In other ways, should the sollution be simple, or efficient?

Comment: i have 110 000 observations. I think that only once.

Comment: And i wonder what should I do with missings? If they are in any column they should be in one category and other values should be divided into two categories?

Comment: Explain how you would do the categorization for a single variable.

Comment: Are you talking about variable selection techniques like lasso, ridge or looking to correlate variables using correlation techniques?

Answer (score 0):

Variable binning might be what you are looking for. In Credit Scoring, Do WOE transformation

Comment: Yes, I' ve read what it is and i think that I should do this. But can explain me how to do this? Is it possible to make it to every variable in the same way with some criteria? Or do I have to make this for every variable single?

Comment: There are methods like individual value combination based on Chisq, quantile split, and IV max split. To start, you can try quantile split(say 10 groups) and combine into 3 groups  by most similar distribution(least chisq value)